# Forming $n$-element subsets, with restrictive condition

Tags: combinatorics

> Question: How many $n$-element subsets $S \subseteq[2n]$ are there so
>   that there are no two elements $x$ and $y$ in $S$ satisfying $x + y = 2n + 1$?
>   Note that $[2n]$ represents the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,2n\}$.

Here is the progress I have made so far in solving this problem.

My process of thinking through this problem has been as follows. First, I calculated the total of possible subsets of $[2n]$, assuming no restriction placed on the subsets. This is a simple choice problem, and the total number of such subsets is ${2n \choose n}$.

Next, I want to determine the number of sets that do not fit the given criteria. If I subtract the number of subsets that violate the restriction from the total number of subsets, then I will get the number of subsets that *do* fit the given criteria.

However, this is where I am having trouble with getting to my solution. We can list the groups of elements that together in one set would violate the restriction:

$1, 2 n$

$2, 2 n - 1$

$\cdots$

$n, n + 1$

I understand that there are $n$ such pairs of elements, but how to count the number of subsets that contain these pairs is where I'm stumped. How do I mathematically calculate the number of these violative subsets? Are there $n$ such subsets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.  You don't want subsets that contain these pairs.  You want subsets that do not contain any of these pairs.  As there are $n$ pairs, you have to choose one from each pair.  How many ways can you do that?

Comment: So there would be $ {n \choose n/2} $ ways to choose these pairs, hence making the final solution $ {2n \choose n} - {n \choose n/2} $ subsets?

Comment: No, you are not choosing pairs.  You have $n$ pairs and choose one item from each one.  If you choose both of a pair those two elements will sum to $2n+1$, which is what you don't want.  For $n=3$ your pairs are $(1,6), (2,5), (3,4)$.  You choose one out of each.  One of the subsets is then $\{1,4,5\}$

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying. So I need to focus on choosing elements within the pairs. There are n pairs, with two possible choices within each pair. So there are 2^n ways?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So, is the 2^n telling me the number of subsets that I don't want? I'm still a bit confused on that point.

Comment: No, it is the number you do want.  We are explicitly constructing the subsets you do want.  The ${2n \choose n}$ is the total number of $n-$subsets but we do not use that.